# How to insert multiple image names in a same row and display it php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am struggling on MySQL help me.
I am using

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO properties (agent_id, property_name, category, location, property_type, search_radius, price, bed_rooms, bath_rooms, commercial_type, area, address, description, image_name, date_added)
                    VALUES ('$agent_id', '$property_name', '$listing_for', '$city', '$property_type', '$area', '$price', '$beds', '$baths', '$commercial_type', '$area_sf', '$address', '$description', '".$filename."',  now() )"  ;
```

This query to insert my values into database. But here `image_name` (`$filename`) contains 3 images. I am getting this names by using array and insert into DB. Here all the fields are single. But image_name contains 3 values. When i use this script inside for loop, then totally 3 rows are inserted. When I use outside for loop it will be inserted last `$filename`. So my need is I want to add all 3 `image_names` and other data into a single row. After that I need to fetch all the data display it. How can I do that. Help me mates. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to store multiple images, then it is clearly one-to-many relation. You need to redesign your MySQL schema.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
foreach ($filename as $key => $value) {
        $array[] = $value; 
    }
    $arrayvalue = json_encode($array);

$sql =  "INSERT INTO properties (agent_id, property_name, category, location, property_type, search_radius, price, bed_rooms, bath_rooms, commercial_type, area, address, description, image_name, date_added)
                VALUES ('$agent_id', '$property_name', '$listing_for', '$city', '$property_type', '$area', '$price', '$beds', '$baths', '$commercial_type', '$area_sf', '$address', '$description', '".$arrayvalue."',  now() )"  ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It shows `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` this error. And null value inserted into table row.

Comment: If $filename is an array, you can use json_encode directly. Like this $filename = array("a","b","c"); $arrayvalue = json_encode($filename);

Comment: `$images_array = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["user_files"]["name"]); $i++) 
  {
     // get the image mime type
      $image_mime = strtolower(image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i])));
 
      if (in_array($image_mime, $valid_image_check)) 
      {
        $folderName = "uploads/";
        $ext = explode("/", strtolower($image_mime));
        $ext = strtolower(end($ext));
        $images_array[] = $filename = rand(10000, 990000) . '_' . time() . '.' . $ext;` I am using like this. But when I insert $images_array, 'Array' name inserted.

Comment: Use json like this `json_encode($images_array);` to insert array's values in DB

Comment: Thank you I created another table. With the reference of property_id. And It will give great result. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to insert images.

```
$images_array   =   array("img1.jpg","img2.jpg","img3.jpg");

$filename   =   implode( ",", $images_array );
```

and in SQL query like

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO properties (agent_id, property_name, category, location, property_type, search_radius, price, bed_rooms, bath_rooms, commercial_type, area, address, description, image_name, date_added)
                    VALUES ('$agent_id', '$property_name', '$listing_for', '$city', '$property_type', '$area', '$price', '$beds', '$baths', '$commercial_type', '$area_sf', '$address', '$description', '".$filename."',  now() )"  ;
```

and when retrieving data use this to get array of images back

```
$images_array   = explode( ",", $data['image_name'] );
```

Comment: Thank you but I am not using img1.jpg, img2.jpg like that I am using `$filename = rand(10000, 990000) . '_' . time() . '.' . $ext;` inside for loop. So randomly it generates image name. So how can I use this help me..

Comment: you cant create `$filename` and insert in the same for loop. First upload all images with one loop and get image names array and then just use insert query.

Comment: before for loop declare `$images_array = array();` .. within loop add images as `$images_array[] = $filename = rand(10000, 990000) . '_' . time() . '.' . $ext;` .. once the loop is completed you'll have your images array.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you told. And I did what you told, But the value Inserted into DB is like 'Array'.

Comment: `$images_array[] =rand(10000, 990000) . '_' . time() . '.' . $ext;` use this in for loop and after loop `$filename   =   implode( ",", $images_array );` .... the use your query.

Comment: Inside for loop I am using `$magicianObj->saveImage($folderName . 'thumb/' . $filename, 100);` to upload image in folder. I change all the values but it not work...

Comment: after `$magicianObj->saveImage($folderName . 'thumb/' . $filename, 100);` add `$images_array[] =$filename;` within that loop thats it....  after that loop ends,  `$filename = implode( ",", $images_array );`  .... the use your query

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
 implode("|",$filename)
```

and in SQL query like

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO properties (agent_id, property_name, category, location, property_type, search_radius, price, bed_rooms, bath_rooms, commercial_type, area, address, description, image_name, date_added)
    VALUES ('$agent_id', '$property_name', '$listing_for', '$city', '$property_type', '$area', '$price', '$beds', '$baths', '$commercial_type', '$area_sf', '$address', '$description', '". implode("|",$filename) ."',  now() )";
```

And similarly use

```
explode("|",$filename)
```

when you retrieve the data